# Get Map Object in Javascript after using CodeIgniter Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps, codeigniter

I'm using the codeigniter library for the google maps api. I load the map using the library located on the CI Wiki: http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/GoogleMapAPI/

I want to then use javascript on the map object after loading the page. How can I get the map object in javascript? Can I use GMap2 on the same div? Won't that recreate the map?

The reason I want to do this is to bind an event to the map.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't looked too deeply at this just yet, but have you tried using `json_encode` on the object and echoing that string into a javascript object (since json is *javascript object notation*)?

Comment: I don't think I can act on that with the google api. Anyone else please know of a way? I can clarify further if you can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "act on that"? Have you tried `<script type="text/javascript">var map = <?php echo json_encode($mapObject)?>;`?

Comment: @treeface would $mapObject be the div object? Because google maps replaces the div with it's own html code, I don't think that the html code would be a valid GMap2 instance. I'm trying to get the GMap2 Instance that was already instantiated. I'll give it a try though and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works:

```
var myMap;

function getMap()
{

if(myMap == null)

    myMap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));

    return myMap;

}
```

and then refer to this function to get reference to the GMap2 object.

Comment: I don't work on this code anymore at work so I can't test it but thank you.